# Cheapest inverter to produce 24VAC

Tags: ac, dc, inverter

I'm working on a sprinkler/lighting controller project where I need to supply solenoids with 24VAC and lighting fixtures with 12VAC. I can use a different circuit for each. The input to the system is about 22V (a square wave rectified through a diode bridge rectifier) and may be lower depending on losses from resistance in the (long) transmission wire. Lowest voltage at the end of the wire will be 14V, with ripple of +/-2V.

I'm looking for the cheapest solution to create 24VAC and 12VAC from the 22VDC supply I have. I have already tried using an H-bridge to generate a sine wave approximation with a microcontroller, but the huge filter required to get an acceptable sine wave out (at least according to LTSpice simulations) is huge and the BOM cost is too high. Typically my loads are at about an amp or less, but the current spikes in the simulations are 2x-3x times that.

Are there other solutions that I'm overlooking that might be able to generate a clean(ish) sine wave? If this is indeed the cheapest way, how can I reduce the current spikes to decrease the needed inductor size? What is considered clean enough when it comes to generating AC?

And no, I can't run the solenoids/lights off 12VDC. Don't ask.

Here's the current H-bridge circuit in question
[image: H-bridge]

And the 34V boost regulator I'm using to power it.
[image: Boost regulator]

Edit: Here's the repository for the simulation: https://github.com/davidcutting42/sprinkler-simulation

Comment: Show your H bridge schematic that you say has current spikes. Explain the losses in the wire feed. Have you calculated what the voltage drop is on full load?

Comment: Wire losses - the inverter is placed somewhere along a 10-12AWG bus that could be up to a mile away from the power supply. Data is being encoded in the square wave that the power supply sends. I'll link the H-bridge schematic above.

Comment: You should reveal what the end DC voltage will be (plus ripple) on full load.

Comment: Lowest voltage at the end of the wire will be 14V, with ripple of +/-2V. Just for numbers.

Comment: What PWM/switching frequency are you using for the H bridge?

Comment: We're generating 60Hz AC with, IIRC, 20 "angles". We're using a special algorithm to decrease harmonics called SHEPWM. So 1200Hz

Comment: Wait. If you have a 22 V square wave, what is the frequency? It is not 50 Hz or 60 Hz by any chance? That might make an acceptable 24 VAC signal all by itself if so.

Comment: No chance. The square wave is switching at 8-10kHz

Comment: OK. Well, I had to ask.

Comment: Were your current spikes definitely there and not just an oscilloscope aberration due to poor probing?

Comment: Just added the LTSpice simulation to the end of my post. Run it and check the current across L1 - it is spiking up to 3A or so.

Comment: Are you sure the solenoids and lights require AC? Will they run on 24V DC and 12V DC?

Comment: As noted in the question, I need to generate AC, not DC. If I run the solenoids/LEDs on DC, it may void their warranty.

Comment: @DavidCutting  Why did you delete this question?. It looks good to me, and a good answer should be able to be provided. Please consider undeleting it - you can always re-delete if it starts to get downvotes - which hopefully it wont.